# trying to call a class, but keep getting message that says that "position takes no arguments

Tags: python-3.x

I have been working with classes however when ever I try to call an object within a class, I keep getting a message saying that the call takes no arguments.  A simple example is in the following where I try to call a card, however it will not show.  Do you have any idea as to what can be causing the issue?

```
class Card(object):
    def _init_(self, symbol, rank):
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.rank = rank
    def show(self):
        print("{} of {}".format(self.rank, self.symbol))


card = Card("clubs", 6)
card.show(self)
```

The following is the error that appears:

```
card = Card("clubs", 6)
TypeError: Card() takes no arguments
```

Comment: You appear to have misspelled `__init__` as `_init_`. You need two underscores on either side of the word `init`!

Comment: Oh my goodness.  Thank you.  I was looking at examples inside my book but did not notice the length on either side of init.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the constructor method `__init__`, with two underscores on either side, not `_init_`.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @jwodder, you have to use `__init__`. Also while calling the `show()` you should call `card.show()`.